# Change in local repo prevents me from pushing to gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

In my local repo, I have series of commits, something like

```
A-B-C-D
```

At commit `D`, I pushed to gitlab.  No problem so far.

Then I needed to make an amend to `D`.  All I changed was the commit message.  But now it was different, with a different ID.  So I have

```
A-B-C-D*
```

I made a few more local commits

```
A-B-C-D*-E-F
```

And then I tried another `git push`, and gitlab wouldn't take it:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '....'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

My first thought was to remove D from gitlab and then do the push again.  (D, BTW, is still the HEAD as far as gitlab knows.)  But I can't see how to do this.  Is there a way?  Failing that, is there some other way to correct the commit at gitlab and pick up where I left off?

Comment: You can rebase your branch onto the remote master

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Thanks.  Could you give some details or a link?  Sounds like just what I need, but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: Search "git rebase tutorial". Command should be something like `git checkout master; git rebase origin/master`

Comment: @iBug   Had trouble because I had to figure out how to unprotect the branch and then protect it again.  (Does it seem like I am new at this?)  But it worked out.  Thanks!